# MLCP privileges

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I grant hadoop-user-read privilege to developers to run MLCP export data. Do I missing any additional privileges for mlcp user?.  developers always get this errors.

```
DEBUG mapreduce.MarkLogicRecordReader: Input query: com.marklogic.xcc.impl.AdhocImpl@1be7bae5
19/11/22 13:08:47 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 0%
19/11/22 13:08:47 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicCounter: 
19/11/22 13:08:47 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: INPUT_RECORDS: 0
19/11/22 13:08:47 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS: 0
19/11/22 13:08:47 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Total execution time: 0 sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to verify that the hadoop-user-read role has permissions to read the documents.  You can view documents permissions using the [xdmp:document-get-permissions](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-get-permissions) command, or by using the [Admin Interface](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/security#id_84784), under *Configure-->Databases-->[DB Name]-->Permissions* and submitting a URI to retrieve the permissions.

You can find more on permissions in the MarkLogic docs:

[Finding Default Permissions](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:default-permissions)

[Setting Document Permissions](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/intro#id_74340)